# sign out google plus from different activity

Tags: android, google-plus, logout, google-signin

I have started using the Google+ API for android, and I have created a sign-in functionality in my application
Now, the problem is that I want to create the sign out button from a different Activity, and what i tried to do didn't really worked..

[Using this link i build sign in functionality](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/MainActivity.java)

Comment: Logging out usually entails one doing a http request to the google plus api I dont understand how it is dependant on your activity. May be if you show us what you tried we could help you

Comment: I use this link to develop sign in functionality.. But i want to logout from next activity not in same activity... Here i am not able to getting mGoogleApiClient is  connected or not

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/MainActivity.java